# Stubbing AWS SES with Sinon and Proxyquire

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, sinon, proxyquire

I'm trying to unit test some code that involves a call to AWS's SES service.

Here's the code in question:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const send = function(options) {
  const SES = new AWS.SES();
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // clipped for brevity
    SES.sendEmail(sesOpts, (error, data) => {
      return error ? reject(error) : resolve(data);
    });
  });
}
module.exports = send;
```

And here's a test, run with Mocha:

```
let SESMock = function() {};
SESMock.prototype.sendEmail = sinon.stub();

const emailHelper = proxyquire('../../src/helpers/email', {
  'aws-sdk': {
    SES: SESMock,
  },
});

it('should call sendEmail', (done) => {
  const opts = {}; // imagine this has the mail sending options
  emailHelper.send(opts).then(() => {
        assert(SESMock.prototype.sendEmail.called);
        done();
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        done();
    });;
});
```

Somehow, despite `done()` being included in both the `then()` and `catch()` callbacks, the test times out every time. I very much expect this is something to do with my setup of the stub, I think I've turned myself around so many times with this that I've lost my bearings altogether.

Can anyone push me in the correct direction to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yup, it was something daft. The sendEmail stub needs to yield:

```
SESMock.prototype.sendEmail = sinon.stub().yields();
```